# $\sigma$-additivity for measure of simple sets: $|\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}M_j|=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|M_j|$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume

A *hyperrectangle* in $\mathbb{R}^d$ has the form $H = I_1 \times \ldots \times I_d$, where $I_1, \ldots, I_d$ are intervals. The natural volume $|H|$ is defined as $|H| : = |I_1| \cdot \ldots \cdot |I_d|$.

A *simple set* $M \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ can be written as finite union $H_1 \cup \ldots \cup H_n$ of disjoint hyperrectangles and the natural measure of $M$ is defined as $|M| : = |H_1| + \ldots + |H_n|$.

Now I want to prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem.**
>   For disjoint simple sets $\{M_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$, where $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} M_j$ is a simple set again, it holds that
>   $$ \left| \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} M_j \right| = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |M_j|.$$

By trying to prove this theorem I realised that the function $|\cdot|$ on simple sets has properties we are used from measures. For example we have $M_1 \subset M_2 \Rightarrow |M_1| \leq |M_2|$. It follows from the definition of $|\cdot|$ that we have

$$ \left| \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} M_j \right| =\left| \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} \bigcup_{i=1}^{k_j}H_{i,j} \right|=  \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k_j}|H_{i,j}| = \sum_{j=1}^{n} |M_j|.$$

At this point I have no idea how to extend this property to countable unions.

Comment: I have a proof, but there is a small section which will be argued slightly differently depending on whether your rectangles are assumed to be open or closed. (The conclusion will be true either way, of course.) Which should I assume?

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'll show that the conclusion holds if we assumes that the intervals are all open, or all closed. Then the arbitrary case will be handled automatically because each interval is sandwiched between an open and a closed interval with the same volume.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer. It's a bit longwinded but it's conceptually pretty straightforward, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the following lemma, which is somewhat annoying to prove, but here is a sketch.

**Lemma:** The union of two (not necessarily disjoint) rectangles $R_1$ and $R_2$ is a simple set, and $|R_1 \cup R_2| \leq |R_1| + |R_2|$.

**Sketch of proof:** We have $R_1 = I_1 \times I_2 \times\cdots\times I_d$ and $R_2 = J_1 \times J_2 \times\cdots\times J_d$, where the $I_k$ and $J_k$ are intervals. Suppose that the combined set of endpoints of $I_k$ and $J_k$ is written in increasing order as $a,b,c,d$. Then $I_k \cup J_k$ can be partitioned canonically as a disjoint union of some or all of the intervals $\{a\}, (a,b), \{b\},  (b,c), \{c\}, (c,d), \{d\}$. We do this for each $k$. Then consider the finite set $\mathcal L$ of all rectangles of the form $L = L_1\times L_2 \times \cdots \times L_d$, where each $L_k$ is one of the intervals in the canonical partition of $I_k \cup J_k$. It's easy to see that these $L$'s are pairwise disjoint. Each $L$ is either contained in $R_1 \cup R_2$ or is disjoint from $R_1 \cup R_2$. If we include only those $L$ which are contained in $R_1 \cup R_2$, then the they form a finite disjoint partition of $R_1 \cup R_2$. Therefore, $R_1 \cup R_2$ is simple as claimed.

Similarly, we can express $R_2 \setminus R_1$ as a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal L$, which shows that $R_2 \setminus R_1$ is also simple.

Finally, we observe that $R_1$ and $R_2 \setminus R_1$ are disjoint, and $R_1 \cup R_2 = R_1 \cup (R_2 \setminus R_1)$, so $|R_1 \cup R_2| = |R_1| + |R_2 \setminus R_1| \leq |R_1| + |R_2|$, where the inequality is due to monotonicity.

---

Note that by induction, the lemma implies that the union of any finite number of (not necessarily disjoint) rectangles $R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_n$ is a simple set, and $|\cup_{n=1}^{N} R_n| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}|R_n|$.

Also by induction, this further implies that the union of any finite number of (not necessarily disjoint) simple sets $M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_n$ is a simple set, and $|\cup_{n=1}^{N} M_n| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}|M_n|$.

---

Now we prove the main result.

Let $A = \cup_{j=1}^{\infty}M_j$ where the $M_j$ are disjoint simple sets.  For finite $J$,
$$A_J = \bigcup_{j=1}^{J}M_j$$
is a finite disjoint union of simple sets, each of which is a finite disjoint union of rectangles, so $A_j$ is simple, and 
$$|A_J| = \sum_{j=1}^{J}|M_j|$$
As $A_J \subset A$, and you have already established monotonicity for simple sets, it follows that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{J}|M_j| = |A_J| \leq |A|$$
This holds for any positive integer $J$, so 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|M_j| = \lim_{J \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{J}|M_j| \leq |A|$$
For the reverse inequality, first, note that since $A$ itself is simple, we can write 
$$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{N}R_n$$
where the $R_n$ are disjoint rectangles, and so $|A| = \sum_{n=1}^{N}|R_n|$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

For each $n=1,2,\ldots,N$, we can find a (possibly empty) closed rectangle $K_n \subset R_n$ with volume $|K_n| \geq |R_n| - \epsilon/N$.

Also, $M = \cup_{j=1}^{\infty}M_j$ is the countable disjoint union of simple sets $M_j$, each of which is a finite disjoint union of rectangles. By increasing the size of these rectangles, we see that $M_j$ is contained in set $U_j$ which is the finite (not necessarily disjoint) union of open rectangles. By the lemma, $U_j$ is simple, and $|U_j|$ is no larger than the sum of the volumes of the open rectangles. We can choose the open rectangles small enough that $|U_j| \leq |M_j| + \epsilon/2^j$.

Then $K = \cup_{n=1}^{N}K_n$ is covered by $\{U_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$, a sequence of open sets. As $K$ is compact, only finitely many of the $U_j$'s are needed, say 
$$K \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{L}U_j$$
Therefore,
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}K_n = K \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{L}U_j$$
The sets on the left and right hand sides are simple (the latter by the lemma), so again by monotonicity, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}|K_n| = \left|\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}K_n\right| \leq \left|\bigcup_{j=1}^{L}U_j\right| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{L}|U_j|$$
where the last inequality is again by the lemma.

So,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}|R_n| - \epsilon \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}|K_n| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{L}|U_j| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|U_j| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|M_j| + \epsilon$$
Therefore,
$$|A| = \sum_{n=1}^{N}|R_n| < \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|M_j| + 2\epsilon$$
As $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that
$$|A| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|M_j|$$